# Как удалить строку из DataGridView, что бы после рефреша строка с таким ID больше не появлялась в списке?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Кто поможет написать код для удалении строк из DataGridView,что бы после рефреша формы или проекта не строка с такой ID больше не появлялся в списке DataGridView

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Напишите, как данные попадают в DataGridView. Они берутся из БД? Сделана привязка (binding)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если удалить все то так:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

если конкретную строчку то надо знать ее индекс

```
dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(индекс строки);
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

можно удалить и имея объект `row`

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: после такого удаления когда снова запускаю программу удаленная строка снова появляется,нужно что бы не появился

Comment: дополнительно вам надо ее еще и из базы удалить. Необходимо знать уникальный идентификатор записи в базе (обычно Id), выполнить запрос на удаление

Answer (score -1):

```
datagridview.databind();
```

вставляешь в любой серверный обработчик

Comment: а по конкретнее?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score -1):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j = j++)
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = null;
            }
        }
```